# Entity Framework - Select * from Entities where Id = (select max(Id) from Entities)

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity set called `Entities` which has a field `Name` and a field `Version`. I wish to return the object having the highest version for the selected `Name`.

SQL wise I'd go

```
Select * 
from table 
where name = 'name' and version = (select max(version)  
                                   from table 
                                   where name = 'name')
```

Or something similar. Not sure how to achieve that with EF. I'm trying to use `CreateQuery<>` with a textual representation of the query if that helps.

Thanks

EDIT:
Here's a working version using two queries. Not what I want, seems very inefficient.

```
var container = new TheModelContainer();
var query = container.CreateQuery<SimpleEntity>(
    "SELECT VALUE i FROM SimpleEntities AS i WHERE i.Name = 'Test' ORDER BY i.Version desc");
var entity = query.Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges).FirstOrDefault();
query =
    container.CreateQuery<SimpleEntity>(
        "SELECT VALUE i FROM SimpleEntities AS i WHERE i.Name = 'Test' AND i.Version =" + entity.Version);
var entity2 = query.Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
Console.WriteLine(entity2.GetType().ToString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
using(var container = new TheModelContainer())
{
    string maxEntityName = container.Entities.Max(e => e.Name);
    Entity maxEntity = container.Entities
                           .Where(e => e.Name == maxEntityName)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

That would select the maximum value for `Name` from the `Entities` set first, and then grab the entity from the entity set that matches that name.

Answer (score 2):

I think from a simplicity point of view, this should be same result but faster as does not require two round trips through EF to sql server, you always want to execute query as few times as possible for latency, as the Id field is primary key and indexed, should be performant

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
var maxEntity = db.Entities.OrderByDecending(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Should be equivalent of sql query

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Entities Order By id desc
```

so to include search term

```
string predicate = "name";

using(var db = new DataContext())
{
var maxEntity = db.Entities
.Where(x=>x.Name == predicate)
.OrderByDecending(x=>x.Id)
.FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this..?

```
        var maxVersion = (from t in table 
                         where t.name == "name"
                         orderby t.version descending
                         select t.version).FirstOrDefault();

        var star = from t in table
                   where t.name == "name" &&
                   t.version == maxVersion
                   select t;
```

Or, as one statement:

```
        var star = from t in table
                   let maxVersion = (
                     from v in table
                     where v.name == "name"
                     orderby v.version descending
                     select v.version).FirstOrDefault()
                   where t.name == "name" && t.version == maxVersion
                   select t;
```

Comment: Interesting to see each answer using a different notation. I prefer this type of notation, but actually use the dot notation more because it seems to suit my dodgy memory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is the easiest way to get max

```
using (MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities())
{
   var maxReservationID = _db .LD_Customer.Select(r => r.CustomerID).Max();
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete at best, as the OP asked _"I wish to return the object..."_, not just the max value (version in the question).